# Can I skip/omit a log4j2 configurationFile that doesn't exist to fall back to an existing one?

Tags: java, xml, spring, log4j2

I am running log4j2 logging in a java application with not the most flexibility in setup. We have an existing `log4j2.xml` configuration file in the classpath of our application that exists within an executable jar. I can modify the jar but not what calls it or is outside of it (I don't control the environment). I would like to add an **optional** overriding log4j2 configuration file outside of the jar. When it exists it overrides log4j2.xml, when it doesn't log4j2.xml is used. So I added this property to a `log4j2.component.properties` file:

```
log4j.configurationFile=../conf/log4j2-override.xml
```

When I create this optional file it works perfectly. When I don't create this file, log4j2 prints an error that the file cannot be found and then fails to fallback to the existing `log4j2.xml` file in the classpath. It doesn't seem to matter if I add the classpath-specific file to the configurationFile property. The configuration file is certainly available because if I remove the property completely it uses the configuration from the jar's classpath.

It's seems log4j2 has an error looking for the file and stops the automatic configuration sequence instead of continuing. Is there anyway for me to optionally override the default configuration xml file without requiring it be present outside the jar if I choose not to? I am hoping to specify this from within the jar file instead of requiring the way in which the jar is called to be changed based on the files existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log4j2.configurationFile` property allows you to specify a comma-separated list of configuration sources, which will be merged using a merge strategy (see [`DefaultMergeStrategy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/composite/DefaultMergeStrategy.html) for the default rules). In your case you can use:

```
log4j2.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2.xml,../conf/log4j2-override.cml
```

Missing files will be ignored and a warning will be sent to the status logger.

Log4j 2.13.x is affected by bug [LOG4J2-2901](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2901), which stops the configuration process if a file is missing. Therefore make sure to use the latest version.

Comment: Ah you're right I was using 2.13.x and that was causing the configuration load to completely stop. Upgrading versions made it fallback to the logging defined in classpath. Unfortunately it prints a warning to console that the location doesn't exist instead of to the fallback logging location itself. Which isn't great for my use case but this does answer my question

Comment: @GalenHowlett: the warning is sent to the [`StatusLogger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/status/StatusLogger.html), which logs problems in Log4j itself. Therefore if the message appears it must end up on the console by design. Unless you increased the level of the status logger, only errors are logged by default and the message will not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Piotr's answer solved the immediate reason why the automatic configuration sequence wasn't working, but it still printed warning messages that didn't work for my use case. So here's an alternative approach that handles the constraints I have around environment (limiting modification to the jar file itself and no console output).

Basically just conditionally set the logger config file within the code itself. I have an application.properties file that unfortunately is not loaded into spring config so I really have to do this manually. You may be able to conditionally specify the `log4j.configurationFile` property from within a standard external spring application.properties file and not even use this code.

```java
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

Properties props = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);

if (props.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile") != null) {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    File file = new File(props.getProperty("log4j.configurationFile"));
    loggerContext.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
}
```